# "Админка" для телефона

Tags: ios

Добрый день, можно ли создать аналог админки для мобильного приложения на ios, как в вебе.
 Проблема такова: Как клиент сможет менять фотографии на своем мобильном приложении?

Comment: В каком смысле "менять"? Загружать новые? А что мешает?

Comment: Загружать новые/ удалять старые. Как клиент сможет это делать? Через хостинг мб?

Comment: Почему не так же, как это делает веб-админка?